# Exibir form de acordo com resposta do user

Tags: .net, vb.net

Preciso de uma ajudinha.

Tenho um `Grid`, com uma coluna denominada `status de interesse`, o tipo dessa coluna é `ComboBox`.

No entanto, quando o user selecionar a opção declinado quero exibir um form x.

Como faço?

Acho que o evento é o `Leave`, mas sobre as condições, como verificarei se o usuário selecionou em tal celula a opção tal?

Aqui tem um exemplo de como está o form.

Comment: Exibir form no evento onclose? sim, é leave.
Form1.show ou hide Não vi a IMG então não sei exatamente como é mas pode ser usado tanto um If elseif como loop ou até um case

Comment: Obrigada. Minha dúvida maior é como será feita a verificação do conteúdo da célula para assim exibir o form. Você tem alguma ideia de como realizar?

Comment: Caso precise de uma checagem antes de exibir a form, faça um If em onclick do grid, assim cada clique no componente será verificado e exibida a form

Comment: Inclua o seu código à pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde @Autoit, a forma de você pegar o campo é assim:

```
grdObjetivo.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
```